# Is it possible to show the output of a doc test in the docs themselves?

Tags: rust, documentation

A simple example:

````
/// ```
/// println!("hello");
/// ```
````

And what I see when I run `cargo doc`:

[image: 1]

It would be useful to show the output. Well, obviously not in this example.

Comment: The current alternative would be to include the output manually [like here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#representation).

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26309) calling for the support of cargo test's `--nocapture` flag for doctests.